# MYSQLI multi query function

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I want to create a function that automatically makes a connection to the database and performs the given queries but I can't get it to work and it gives no errors.
I think I'm not outputting in the correct way my goal is to output a array that stores all the returned values from the queries.

Here is my code so far hope you can help:

```
public function db_query() {
    $ini = parse_ini_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/app.ini');
    $mysqli = new mysqli($ini['db_location'], $ini['db_user'], $ini['db_password'], $ini['db_name']);

    // create string of queries separated by ;
    $query = "SELECT name FROM mailbox;";
    $query .= "SELECT port FROM mailbox";

    // execute query - $result is false if the first query failed
    $result = mysqli_multi_query($mysqli, $query);

    if ($result) {
        do {
            // grab the result of the next query
            if (($result = mysqli_store_result($mysqli, 0)) === false && mysqli_error($mysqli) != '') {
                echo "Query failed: " . mysqli_error($mysqli);
                while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                    echo $row[0];
                }
            }
        } while (mysqli_more_results($mysqli) && mysqli_next_result($mysqli)); // while there are more results
    } else {
        echo "First query failed..." . mysqli_error($mysqli);
    }
}
```

> Note: I did not add the parameter for the query just for testing
>   purposes.

Comment: `SELECT name, port FROM mailbox` is __enough__

Comment: I added multiple queries to 1 table to test the function

Comment: Inside your `do {` loop you are only echoing anything in the case where the store_result operation fails. If it succeeds, nothing is echoed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function db_query($mysqli) {

    $return = [];
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT name FROM mailbox");
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        $return[] = $row[0];
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT port FROM mailbox");
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        $return[] =  $row[0];
    }
    return $return;
}
```

simple, clean, efficient, always works

Comment: In addition, check the $result before entering the while loop.

Comment: No, you should never check the result manually. Configure mysqli to report errors instead

Comment: This should have been only one query. Why execute it twice?

Comment: @Dharman beause it's [only for test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60038622/mysqli-multi-query-function/60038779?noredirect=1#comment106181048_60038622)